# how to pass Arraylist<BeanClass> from one activity to another?

Tags: android, serializable, parcelable

i have two activities named "Activity A" and "Activity B". In my Activity A i need to pass `Arraylist<BeanClass>` to Activity B. Here is Activity A code....

```
Arraylist<BeanClass> list;
list.add(new BeanClass(nm, Add, Phn));
Intent i = new Intent(Activity A.this,Activity B.class);
```

now how to pass `list` to next activity and receive it as well...

Here is a BeanClass.java

```
public class BeanClass 
{
    String name,address,phone;

    BeanClass(String name,String address,String phone)
    {

        this.name=name;
        this.address=address;
        this.phone=phone;
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized the `Arraylist<BeanClass> list;` and you're passing wrong parameters. Please post *correct* code.

Comment: Actually i did that in my code but forgot to do it here....

Comment: how wrong parameters..?? nm,Add,phn are String itself...

Comment: i need to know that which kind of "putExtra" method i can use here

Comment: [**Please See this Blog**](http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-pass-boolean-int-string-integer.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make `BeanClass` class to serializable.

```
public class BeanClass implements Serializable
{
  //fields
  //constructors
  //setter/getter 
}
```

Prepare the `List` and pass it via `Intent.putExtra()`

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
 ArrayList<BeanClass> list=new ArrayList<BeanClass>();
 list.add(new BeanClass(nm, Add, Phn));
 ...

 intent.putExtra("list", list); 
 startActivity(intent);
```

And receive the `List` in `NextActivity's onCreate` method

```
 Intent intent=getIntent();
 ArrayList<BeanClass> list=(ArrayList<BeanClass>)intent.getSerializableExtra("list");
```

Comment: Can i do the same with Vector instead of ArrayList ?

Comment: Yes, Vector is serializable. But why are you *interested* in **legacy** API?

Comment: As i am beginner i dont have any idea about the legacy API and serializable. Can you briefly explain that stuff ? Thanks for your valuable comments....

Comment: Is there any drawback with legacy API ?